# How to display page content in custom theme in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, content-type

I have been searching for this a few hours now and I might just overlook it or asking the wrong questions in google, but I would really like to know how I can get the content I type in e.g. the About page in the WordPress dashboard, to display on my `page.php`.

Comment: do you need to show using specific post ID?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to get the content of a particular page so you can add it to your page template (so it will be displayed on every page)?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content of any arbitrary page like this:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('About');
```

I'm grabbing the page by the title, you can also get it [by ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) or [URL path](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)

You can then display it by outputting the `post_content` property of the [post object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). Note that if you need it to be formatted, you'll need to apply the `the_content` filter:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show a specific post/page by id, Wordpress has the function

```
<?php get_post( $id, $output, $filter ); ?>
```

Documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post